# Strange bug with Vaadin 8 Grid

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin8, vaadin-grid

I have a strange floating bug with Vaadin grid appears from time to time. The first thing is grid has row duplicates provided that the data is not duplicated. The second is when i click on dublicated row click event may contain value of the corresponding row or adjacent row. Seems like rows overlap each other.

**Explanation:**

[image: Pic. №1]

On the picture above (Pic. №1) we can see grid. Let's consider three rows: AHTO-18, AHTO-22, AHTO-29 (values of first column). If I click on the first AHTO-18 expected behavior is window with details of AHTO-18 should be opened. But opened window contains details of another row (AHELAID instead of AHTO-18). It can be seen on the picture below (Pic. №2).

[image: Pic. №2]

Then I scroll down the grid and find this very three rows (AHTO-18, AHTO-22, AHTO-29) a second time. It can be seen on picture below (Pic. №3).

[image: Pic. №3]

Finaly if click on AHTO-18 found a second time window with details of correct row is opened.

**Code:**

```
protected DataProvider<EstonianShipDTO, Void> createDataProvider() {
    return DataProvider.fromCallbacks(
            query -> {
                final FindEstonianShipsRequestDTO request = FindEstonianShipsRequestDTO.builder()
                        .criteria(getSearchFormCriteria())
                        .build();

                final List<SortDTO.OrderDTO> orders = query.getSortOrders().stream()
                        .map(queryOrder -> SortDTO.OrderDTO.builder()
                                .property(queryOrder.getSorted())
                                .direction(queryOrder.getDirection() == SortDirection.DESCENDING ? DirectionEnum.DESC : DirectionEnum.ASC)
                                .build()
                        )
                        .collect(toList());

                if (orders.isEmpty()) {
                    orders.add(SortDTO.OrderDTO.builder()
                            .property("shipName")
                            .direction(DirectionEnum.ASC)
                            .build());
                }

                request.setSort(SortDTO.builder().orders(orders).build());

                return estonianShipService.findAll(request, query.getOffset(), query.getLimit()).getContent().stream();
            },
            query -> (int) estonianShipService.count(FindEstonianShipsRequestDTO.builder()
                    .criteria(getSearchFormCriteria())
                    .build())
    );
}

private Grid<EstonianShipDTO> createSearchResultsGrid() {
    final Grid<EstonianShipDTO> grid = new Grid<>();
    grid.setId("ships-area-grid");
    grid.setHeightByRows(DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE);
    grid.setDataProvider(createDataProvider());
    grid.setSizeFull();
    grid.setSelectionMode(Grid.SelectionMode.SINGLE);
    if (ALL_SHIPS.equals(getSearchFormCriteria().getShipState())) {
        grid.setStyleGenerator((StyleGenerator<EstonianShipDTO>) item -> {
            if (NOT_REGISTERED_SHIPS.equals(item.getShipState())) {
                return "yellow_row";
            } else if (REDEEMED_SHIPS.equals(item.getShipState())) {
                return "grey_row";
            } else {
                return "white_row";
            }
        });
    }

    // Grid Columns
    final Grid.Column shipNameColumn = grid.addColumn(EstonianShipDTO::getShipName)
            .setId(COLUMN_SHIP_NAME)
            .setCaption(messageSource.getMessage("views.ships.results.form.name.caption", null, VaadinSession.getCurrent().getLocale()))
            .setExpandRatio(1)
            .setDescriptionGenerator(item -> "Laeva ID: " + item.getId() + ofNullable(item.getRegistrationDate()).map(regDate -> "\n" + "Registreerimise kuup\u00e4ev: " + regDate.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(Constants.DATE_FORMAT))).orElse(""));

    final Grid.Column regNumberColumn = grid.addColumn(EstonianShipDTO::getRegistrationNumber)
            .setId(COLUMN_REG_NUMBER)
            .setCaption(messageSource.getMessage("views.ships.results.form.regNumber.caption", null, VaadinSession.getCurrent().getLocale()))
            .setExpandRatio(1);

    final Grid.Column callSignColumn = grid.addColumn(EstonianShipDTO::getCallSign)
            .setId(COLUMN_CALL_SIGN)
            .setCaption(messageSource.getMessage("views.ships.results.form.callSign.caption", null, VaadinSession.getCurrent().getLocale()))
            .setExpandRatio(1);

    final Grid.Column mmsiNumberColumn = grid.addColumn(EstonianShipDTO::getMmsiNumber)
            .setId(COLUMN_MMSI_NUMBER)
            .setCaption(messageSource.getMessage("views.ships.results.form.mmsiNumber.caption", null, VaadinSession.getCurrent().getLocale()))
            .setExpandRatio(1);

    final Grid.Column imoNumberColumn = grid.addColumn(EstonianShipDTO::getImoNumber)
            .setId(COLUMN_IMO_NUMBER)
            .setCaption(messageSource.getMessage("views.ships.results.form.imoNumber.caption", null, VaadinSession.getCurrent().getLocale()))
            .setExpandRatio(1);

    final Grid.Column regDateColumn = grid.addColumn(EstonianShipDTO::getRegistrationDate, new LocalDateRenderer(Constants.DATE_FORMAT))
            .setId(COLUMN_REG_DATE)
            .setCaption(messageSource.getMessage("views.ships.results.form.regDate.caption", null, VaadinSession.getCurrent().getLocale()))
            .setExpandRatio(1);

    final Grid.Column shipTypeColumn = grid.addColumn(EstonianShipDTO::getSailType)
            .setId(COLUMN_SHIP_TYPE)
            .setCaption(messageSource.getMessage("views.ships.results.form.sailType.caption", null, VaadinSession.getCurrent().getLocale()))
            .setExpandRatio(1);

    grid.addSelectionListener(event -> OptionalConsumer.of(event.getFirstSelectedItem())
            .ifPresent(item -> deleteButton.setEnabled(true))
            .ifNotPresent(() -> deleteButton.setEnabled(false))
    );

    grid.addComponentColumn(item -> {
        final MButton editButton = new MButton()
                .withCaption(messageSource.getMessage(isEditEnabled ? "views.common.buttons.open.caption" : "views.common.buttons.view.caption", null, VaadinSession.getCurrent().getLocale()))
                .withStyleName(ValoTheme.BUTTON_TINY);
        editButton.addClickListener(click -> {
            // add item ID to the location
            final String itemId = getId(item);
            final String uriFragment = UI.getCurrent().getPage().getUriFragment();
            final String newUriFragment;

            if (StringUtils.contains(uriFragment, "/id/")) {
                newUriFragment = substringBeforeLast(uriFragment, "/id/") + "/id/" + itemId;
            } else {
                newUriFragment = uriFragment + "/id/" + itemId;
            }

            UI.getCurrent().getPage().setUriFragment(newUriFragment, false);

            // show popup window
            openItemDetailsWindow(getId(item));
        });

        return new MHorizontalLayout()
                .withStyleName("rowButtons")
                .withSpacing(true)
                .with(editButton);
    })
            .setStyleGenerator(person -> "buttonsColumn")
            .setExpandRatio(-1);

    updateGridHeight(grid);

    return grid;
}

private void updateGridHeight(Grid<EstonianShipDTO> grid) {
    final long count = estonianShipService.count(FindEstonianShipsRequestDTO.builder()
            .criteria(getSearchFormCriteria())
            .build());

    totalResultAmount.setCaption(
            messageSource.getMessage("views.ships.search.total.caption", new Long[]{count}, VaadinSession.getCurrent().getLocale())
    );

    if (count <= DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE) {
        grid.setHeightByRows(count < 1 ? 1 : count);
    } else {
        grid.setHeightByRows(DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE);
    }
}
```

**EstonianShipDTO**

```
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = "id")
public class EstonianShipDTO {
    @Min(0)
    private Double boardHeight;
    @Length(max = 7)
    private String boardNumber;
    private ShipBodyMaterialDTO bodyMaterial;
    @Min(0)
    private Double brt;
    @Length(max = 10)
    private String callSign;
    @Min(0)
    private Double carryingCapacity;
    private LocalDate certificateValidFrom;
    private LocalDate certificateValidUntil;
    private Long chartererId;
    private AgencyDTO classificationAgency;
    @Length(max = 10)
    private String classificationCertificateNumber;
    @Length(max = 150)
    private String classificationNote;
    @Length(max = 255)
    private String constructionNote;
    private ConstructionSiteDTO constructionSite;
    @Min(Constants.YEAR_MIN_VALUE)
    @Max(Constants.YEAR_MAX_VALUE)
    private Integer constructionYear;
    private LocalDate dateOnTheKeel;
    @Min(0)
    private Integer deckCount;
    @Min(0)
    private Double diveDepth;
    @Min(0)
    private Double fullLength;
    @Min(0)
    private Integer grossTonnage;
    @Length(max = 15)
    private String hinCin;
    @Length(max = 70)
    private String hydroParameters;
    private IceClassDTO iceClass;
    private Long id;
    @Min(Constants.IMO_MIN_VALUE)
    @Max(Constants.IMO_MAX_VALUE)
    private Integer imoNumber;
    private Boolean isSmallVessel;
    @Min(0)
    private Double length;
    @Min(Constants.MMSI_MIN_VALUE)
    @Max(Constants.MMSI_MAX_VALUE)
    private Integer mmsiNumber;
    @Min(0)
    private Integer netCapacity;
    @Min(0)
    private Integer netTonnage;
    @Min(0)
    private Double nrt;
    private Long ownerId;
    @Min(0)
    private Integer passengerAmount;
    @Min(0)
    private Integer peopleAmount;
    private PortDTO port;
    @Min(0)
    private Double power;
    private ShipBodyMaterialDTO reconstructionBodyMaterial;
    @Length(max = 255)
    private String reconstructionNote;
    private ConstructionSiteDTO reconstructionSite;
    @Min(Constants.YEAR_MIN_VALUE)
    @Max(Constants.YEAR_MAX_VALUE)
    private Integer reconstructionYear;
    private LocalDate redeemedDate;
    private RegistryDTO register;
    private LocalDate registrationDate;
    @NotEmpty
    @Length(max = 10)
    private String registrationNumber;
    private RegistryChapterDTO registryChapter;
    private Long registryChapterId;
    private SailTypeEnum sailType;
    @Length(max = 30)
    private String shipName;
    private ShipSearchTypeEnum shipState;
    private ShipTypeDTO shipType;
    private AgencyDTO supervisoryDepartment;
    @Min(0)
    private Integer tonnageFrom;
    @Min(0)
    private Integer tonnageTo;
    private TradeZoneDTO tradeZone;
    private LocalDate underSupervisionFrom;
    private LocalDate underSupervisionUntil;
    private LocalDateTime updateDate;
    private UserDTO updateUser;
    @Min(0)
    private Double width;
}
```

Comment: My first guess is that there is something wrong with equals() your data bean.

Comment: Try to make a SSCCE. It is difficult to help you otherwise.

Comment: @TatuLund, It was my first assumption, but didn't solve the problem.

Comment: @SteffenHarbich, I added explanation with pictures. Hope it's become clear.

Comment: The behavior is clear now. I didn't encounter a similar problem. You could share some code which we can review or try to isolate the error by removing code step by step. Or if you start from scratch with a simple example grid you may be able to reproduce the issue and report here.

Comment: @SteffenHarbich I added code exmaples. And one interesting feature. If i click on header column to apply sorting problem disappear.

Comment: Code looks fine so far. Can you add the `EstonianShipDTO` class?

Comment: Do you use the latest Vaadin version 8.4.3?

Comment: @SteffenHarbich, yes i use 8.4.3 version of Vaadin. I added EstonianShipDTO

Comment: Did you try to implement `hashCode` and `equals` manually? Maybe Vaadin has problems with lombok, I don't know.

Comment: @SteffenHarbich yes, i've implemented equals() and hashCode() manualy but it had no result.